# Unwanted volume change with multiple input busses, Apple Core Audio Mixer Host

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-audio, volume, mixer

I'm working on an iPhone App that uses Apple's mixer host example as a starting point.  I successfully added some new sound files and added new input busses for the sounds.  I set all of the input volumes to the same value in the main view controller that houses the audio object.

```
[audioObject enableMixerInput: 0 isOn: TRUE];
[audioObject enableMixerInput: 1 isOn: TRUE];
[audioObject enableMixerInput: 2 isOn: TRUE];
[audioObject enableMixerInput: 3 isOn: TRUE];

[audioObject setMixerOutputGain: 1.000];

[audioObject setMixerInput: 0 gain: 1.000];
[audioObject setMixerInput: 1 gain: 1.000];
[audioObject setMixerInput: 2 gain: 1.000];
[audioObject setMixerInput: 3 gain: 1.000];
```

I trigger all the sounds in the same callback function of the mixer host.

The problem is that when multiple sounds are playing at the same time, the the overall volume becomes quieter.  Then when just one sound is playing again, it becomes louder.  I wonder why.  How can I fix this so that the sounds always stay the same volume?

Comment: OK, found out how to solve it.

The problem was that I was returning out of the callback function, not allowing it to fall through and process data for all of the busses.  The callback needed to set all of those other bus frame buffers to zero instead of doing nothing.

    // must do this for input busses that aren't playing to keep volume constant
    outSamplesChannelLeft[frameNumber]       = 0;
    if (isStereo) 
        outSamplesChannelRight[frameNumber]  = 0;